# Access twitter with C# using LINQ to Twitter

Tags: c#, twitter, linq-to-twitter

I trying to create a Winforms app in VS for search a specific keyword and retrieve the tweet display in my app.
Below is my code which trying to get 100 tweet from my profile and make a call to the new method in my form's constructor, followed by assignment of the data to the main tweets list box on my form

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using LinqToTwitter; 

    public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            private SingleUserAuthorizer authorizer =
             new SingleUserAuthorizer
             {
                 CredentialStore = new
                SingleUserInMemoryCredentialStore
                 {
                     ConsumerKey ="",
                     ConsumerSecret ="",
                     AccessToken ="",
                     AccessTokenSecret =""
                 }
             };

            private List<Status> currentTweets;
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                GetMostRecent100HomeTimeLine();
                lstTweetList.Items.Clear();
                currentTweets.ForEach(tweet =>
                   lstTweetList.Items.Add(tweet.Text));
            }
            private void GetMostRecent100HomeTimeLine()
            {
                var twitterContext = new TwitterContext(authorizer);

                var tweets = from tweet in twitterContext.Status
                             where tweet.Type == StatusType.Home &&
                             tweet.Count == 100
                             select tweet;

                currentTweets = tweets.ToList();
            }
```

[An unhandled exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll] are occur inside the code below

```
currentTweets = tweets.ToList();
```

My guess is it's the LinqToTwitter library trying to enumerate the 'tweets' collection and finding there's either no data, or the data cannot be retrieved.
I am beginner to this topic and this is my project.

Hope someone can guide me to solve the problem

Comment: Please add a inner exception type and text to your question.

Comment: The `&& tweet.Count == 100` clause in your `where` statement looks wrong. This will only select a tweet if it's `Count` is 100. Surely this isn't always the case. What happens if you take it out?

Comment: Still the same problem occur

Answer (score 0):

LINQ to Twitter is async. So you should use `async` and `await` keywords in your code. It also means it isn't a good idea to put the query in the constructor. In this case, I would use the `Form.Load` event. Assuming, you hooked up a `Form1_Load` handler to the `Form1` `Load` event, you could re-write the code like this:

```
        public async void Form1_Load()
        {
            await GetMostRecent100HomeTimeLine();
            lstTweetList.Items.Clear();
            currentTweets.ForEach(tweet =>
               lstTweetList.Items.Add(tweet.Text));
        }
        private async Task GetMostRecent100HomeTimeLine()
        {
            var twitterContext = new TwitterContext(authorizer);

            var tweets = from tweet in twitterContext.Status
                         where tweet.Type == StatusType.Home &&
                         tweet.Count == 100
                         select tweet;

            currentTweets = await tweets.ToListAsync();
        }
```

Notice that the `Form1_Load` method is `async`. It also returns `void`, which is necessary and should only be used in top level async event handlers. It `awaits` the task returned by `GetMostRecent100HomeTimeLine`.

The `GetMostRecent100HomeTimeLine` method is `async` too, but returns `Task`. All of your methods in the async call chain, below the initial `async void` event handler, should return `Task` or `Task<T>`. This lets you `await` their tasks so that the calling method doesn't return before the called method is complete.

Finally, notice that the code `awaits` the task returned from `ToListAsync`. While the compiler lets you use `ToList` (without the await), it won't work at runtime because LINQ to Twitter is async and expects you to await it's operators, like `ToListAsync`, `SingleOrDefaultAsync`, or `FirstOrDefaultAsync`.

You can also use `try/catch` handlers to catch any exceptions thrown. LINQ to Twitter wraps most exceptions in a `TwitterQueryException` that will contain any error messages and associated codes from the Twitter API.